# Content scroll over background image - iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, image, mobile, background

I am using a full page image background on a bootstrap template which allows text to scroll over the background when viewed on a desktop.

```
.background_html {
background: url(http://*******.com/web/4.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

I have used a media query to load a smaller size image for mobile devices:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.custom_bg_5 {
background: url(http://******.com/web/4_sm.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: auto auto; 
-moz-background-size: auto auto; 
-o-background-size: auto auto;
background-size: auto auto;
}
}
```

This resizes the image correctly but the image doesn't remain fixed and just scrolls with the text. This leaves a blank space beneath the image as I scroll down (ie when the bottom of the image has been reached).

I want the text to just scroll over a fixed background image on mobile devices.

Is there a fix for this yet?